# How to call observable that loads additional contents to a object transforming it in another observable?

Tags: java, android, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I have this `MyCollectionInteractor` that loads all `CollectionItemVO` from a firebase database:

```
public interface MyCollectionInteractor extends BaseInteractor{
    Single<List<CollectionItemVO>> load ();
}
```

CollectionItemVO is:

```
public class CollectionItemVO {
    String beerId;
    long timestamp;
    int quantity;

    public CollectionItemVO() {
    }


    public CollectionItemVO(String beerId, long timestamp, int quantity) {
        this.beerId = beerId;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
}
```

So I have this `CollectionItem`:

```
public class CollectionItem {

    private final CollectionItemVO itemVOList;
    private final Beer beer;

    public CollectionItem(Beer beer, CollectionItemVO itemVOList) {
        this.beer = beer;
        this.itemVOList = itemVOList;
    }

}
```

That has a complete Beer object. To load that object I use this other interactor:

```
public interface LoadBeerInteractor extends BaseInteractor {
    Flowable<Beer> load(String beerId);
}
```

I want to transform this `CollectionInteractor.load` call into an `Observable` that emits `CollectionItem` and I want to use `LoadBeerInteractor.load(beerId)` to delivery CollectionItem with full beer object.

For what I studied, I believe it is possible to do that using flatmap but I have not been able to achieve the desired result yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to do something like this:

```
MyCollectionInteractor collections = ...
LoadBeerInteractor beers = ...

Flowable<CollectionItem> items = collections.load()
    .toFlowable()
    .flatMapIterable(it -> it) // unpack from Flow<List<T>> to Flow<T>
    .flatMap(it ->
        beers
            .load(it.beerId)
            .map(beer -> new CollectionItem(beer, it))
    )
```

This might also work:

```
Flowable<CollectionItem> items = collections.load()
    .toFlowable()
    .flatMap(list ->
        Flowable
            .from(list)
            .flatMap(it -> 
                beers
                    .load(it.beerId)
                    .map(beer -> new CollectionItem(beer, it))
            )
    )
```